# Export Google Sheet as TXT file (Fixed Width)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to replicate some functionality from a Excel document with some macros in a Google Spreadsheet. The end goal is to export a fixed-width txt file. Unfortunately, the vendor cannot use a CSV file. So, does anybody know of a way to generate a fixed-width TXT file using Google Scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anybody else comes looking. I used a few sources and came up with this:

```
function saveAsFixedWidthTxt() {
  // get Spreadsheet Name
  var fileName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  //var fileName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();

  // get Directory the Spreadsheet is stored in.
  var dirName = DocsList.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).getParents()[0].getName();

  // Add the ".txt" extension to the file name
  fileName = fileName + ".txt";

  // Convert the range data to fixed width format
  var txtFile = convertRangeToTxtFile_(fileName);

  // Delete existing file
  deleteDocByName(fileName);

  // Create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the data
  DocsList.getFolder(dirName).createFile(fileName, txtFile);
}

function convertRangeToTxtFile_(txtFileName) {
  try {
    var txtFile = undefined;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = rows.getValues();

    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var txt = "";
      for (var row = 2; row < data.length; row++) {

        for (var j=6; j<=10; j++){

          if(data[row][j] != ''){

            // Employee ID
            var empID = "" + data[row][3];
            txt += empID;
            //Fill to 6 characters
            for (i=empID.length; i<6; i++){
              txt += " ";
            }

            // Name
            var fullName = data[row][5] + " " + data[row][4]
            txt += fullName;
            //Fill to 43 characters
            for (i=fullName.length; i<44; i++){
              txt += " ";
            }

            // etc, etc to build out your line

            txt += "\r\n";
          }
        }
      }
      txtFile = txt;
    }
    return txtFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}

function deleteDocByName(fileName){
  var docs=DocsList.find(fileName)
  for(n=0;n<docs.length;++n){
    if(docs[n].getName() == fileName){
      var ID = docs[n].getId()
      DocsList.getFileById(ID).setTrashed(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

1. export the sheet as a `xlsx`, then open that file in Excel.
2. Export that file as `Space Delimited Text` (`.prn`, for some reason).
3. Change the file extension on the resultant file to `.txt`.

This will result in a file like this:

```
Column    Another   Column 3
Val 1            2  $    5.00
```

Or do you need to get a `.txt` file directly out of Google Apps Script?

**Edit** since a direct `.txt` download is necessary.

Here's how you could design a script to do that:

1. Find a way to convert `sheet.getColumnWidth(n)` to a number of spaces. You may find that there are 5 pixels to 1 character, or whatever the ratio
2. Run `getColumnWidth()` for each column to find the width you need for each column. *Alternatively, find the length longest string in each cell.*
3. Go through each cell and add it to a large string you begin building. As you add it, add the number of spaces necessary to match the value converted from `getColumnWidth()`. At the end of each row, append `\n` to represent a new line.

Once the output string is complete, you could then use the [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service) to download the text like so:

```
ContentService.createTextOutput(youBigString).downloadAsFile('filename.txt')
```

This would involve deploying your script as a web app, which could work well - you'd go to a URL and the page would trigger a download of the fixed-width file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to go straight from Google to the text file.

Comment: Is it possible to get a direct download link like this:https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id= ? How to get such url for google script data?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, DocList use returns ReferenceError.@MSCF your lines 7 & 27 :

```
var dirName = DocsList.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).getParents()[0].getName();

DocsList.getFolder(dirName).createFile(fileName, txtFile);
```

become

```
var dirName = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).getParents().next().getId();

DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).getParents().next().createFile(fileName, txtFile);
```